# How to launch a substrate blockchain as a test network?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate, polkadot-js

Please forgive my stupid question here.

[image]

To launch my node-template under the **TEST NETWORKS** category, do I need to host my own polkadot/apps like what [GeekCash](https://my.geekcash.org/#/explorer) did?

What is the correct command to perform on `substrate-node-template`? the examples are always`--dev --tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your local-running testnet through Polkadot.js Apps, scroll down in this sidebar to "local development" and enter the URL to your running node, probably something like `ws://localhost:9944` if you didn't make any changes. You will not be deploying this as a test network, because that section of the UI is just for long-running test networks by teams that want to test their functionality long-term. For throwaway use cases of local development, use Local Development by scrolling down in the sidebar.